# Replacement for huge case statements

Tags: java, design-patterns, hook

I'm trying to improve a Java project which uses a lot of large case statements. In cases where the case statement is used, it is used to handle an event which has an attribute associated to it. For example:

```
public void jumpOverWall(int wallID) {
    switch (wallID) {
            case 0:
            case 1213:
            case 2123:
            case 3123:
            case 4123:
    }
}
```

The numbers are non sequential and all require a different action to be performed - for example saying "You cannot jump over this wall" or moving the character to a set position. There are very few cases in which the case response follows a set pattern. What I mean by this is that the switch statements do not follow a pattern that would allow for code similar to:

```
public void jumpOverWall(int wallID) {
    someArray[1213] = 10;
    someArray[3123] = 20;

    if (playerJumpingSkill > someArray[wallID]) {
            // Do something
    } else {
            sendPlayerMessage("You cannot do this!");
    }
}
```

Therefore, I am wondering the best possible way of handling these 'events'. The whole idea of an 'event handler' style system is something that appeals to me but I am stuck as how to implement it (or a better solution to the problem). There are too many 'events' (in my opinion) to have a separate class for each one.

Is there a method / design for hooking events? Would this be applicable / work. I'd be looking to a method of easy hooking such as:

```
hookEvent(1213, new SomeInterface() {
    boolean eventOK() {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then these 'hooks' would be checked for and called?

Comment: Are the cases in the switch statement identifiers or do those numbers somehow represent a value that can be used to compute a result? For example does `1213` mean "multiply 1213 by the players level minus his penalties" or is it just an index?

Comment: See also: [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: Is `//Do something` based on a fixed set of possible actions? For example are `1213, 3123` both "Break through wall like Kool-Aid man" and `4123, 5123` are "Fall off wall"?

Comment: For the most part, the options are fixed but each 'identifier' could require additional things to happen and the actions themselves require additional parameters passed with the 'wallID' style variable - e.g. jumpingFromX, jumpingFromY

Comment: I highly suggest replacing the numbers with enums. Imagine looking at this code months later and wondering what `if(eventId == 1234) { ...` does..

Comment: are most of your cases fall throughs and you only have say 20 different things to actually call events on or is there an event for all 100+ items?

Comment: @BrendanLong The eventId is a number given to this part of the program - I'm not calling doEvent(RUN_AWAY); from somewhere else. It receives the eventId from the event and then has to process it. Would you recommend transferring those eventIDs from the client into enums and then using those enums?

Comment: @JPM 99% of items have their own event.

Comment: @jSherz - Yes, I'd use enums wherever possible when the value of the number isn't important. Anything that helps with readability cuts down on bugs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a separate method for each case? That way, it makes your code more readable.

```
public void jumpOverWall(int wallID)
{
      switch (wallID) 
        {
        case 0:     methodA(wallID); break; // you could of course have a more descriptive name here.
        case 1213:  methodB(wallID); break; 
        case 2123:  methodC(wallID); break;
        case 3123:  methodD(wallID); break;
        case 4123:  methodE(wallID); break;
        }
}
```

Comment: My only problem with that most of the switch statements have ~100+ items which would require the same number of functions. I suppose this is possible, I'm just looking for the best solution - but thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: +1, in my opinion a switch statement would be the most succinct way to encode this, provided the actions each consist of a single statement or method call.

Comment: I've decided on this method as it seems the simplest - I'm still very much a beginner at Java - and will save me the trouble of having to create numerous classes for each wallID. Thanks again!

Comment: @jSherz: I've added some benefits at the end of my post, just to make sure you know...

Answer (score 6):

Command pattern may be better option for you. Say, you have command object implementing 
interface:

```
public Interface Command {
      void processEvent(Event e);
}
```

Then you can have some hash of commands, keyed by event codes - much more readable.   And you can even  use DI container (spring is most popular, but there is also picocontainer or google guice,  and surely I missed some) for command object  creation - just register respective objects with keys as event codes.  This will save you code for population of a hash.

And it even does not have to be a lot of clases -  it could be just differently configured instances (depending on your use case) -  no class exposion today

Comment: +1, I think this is the best option.  OP doesn't like the class explosion problem but I don't think it's a big deal and you're going to have a lot of code anyway...

Comment: Absolutely.  The command pattern is your best friend in these cases.  Depending on your app, you can even construct a series of singletons that all implement the procesEvent(Arg one, Arg two, ..., Arg n) and you can handle each case separately.  You can even combine a group of commands into logical groups so you can re-use groups of commands...so long as it still implements the interface.  If you really have a lot of cases, and some are shared, the grouping technique can really help you.

Comment: @Konstantin Pribluda, could you please explain a little, the `switch` (or `when` in Kotlin, particularly in my case) operator without an else branch forces a developer to provide implementation for every item in the enum, so it's a kind of compilation-time constraint, which works well, I would say. The question is how does the approach suggested by you  cover that point, Does it provide any checks on compilation time?

Comment: Gosh,  8n Year old answer.    No, there is no compile time check in this case -  but also kind of more flexible solution which will allow you to add new cases without  touch to other code.

Answer (score 1):

Since your wallIDs are really purely identifiers, and each one handles jumpOverWall differently, you do need different code anyways. So I would **really use different classes for your wallIDs**. That way, you can let dynamic dispatch do the case distinction. I do not understand why you think

> There are too many 'events' to have a separate class
>   for each one.

Since you need different code anyways, using classes does not blow up your code.

Alternatively, you can use **Enums with constant-specific method implementations**:

```
public enum WallID {
1213 { returnType jumpOverWall(Wall wall){ //... 
  } },
3213 { returnType jumpOverWall(Wall wall){ //...
  } },
1332 { returnType jumpOverWall(Wall wall){ //...
  } },

//you can also use better names for your constants ;)

abstract returnType jumpOverWall(Wall wall);
}
```

You can read in detail how this works, and why you should prefer enums over your int IDs (since they are really purely identifiers) in [Josh Bloch's Effective Java, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 30 (Use enums instead of int constants).

#### Update:

By using one of these two approaches instead of int IDs and a switch statement, you get several advantages:

- more modular appraoch, hence more readable and following SRP
- more reusable, e.g. when you want to inherit some jumpOverWall behavior
- you can associating further data with each constant
- you can providing further methods for the constants, again constant specific, if you like
- and what I find most important: safety by utilizing Java's type system and dynamic dispatch.

Comment: I don't really want to have a few hundred class files - would you recommend putting multiple classes in the same file in this case? And how would the classes be named / called?

Comment: A few hundred class files sounds a bit tedious, but I don't see any real show stopper in that. Are int IDs really appropriate? Usually, they are artificial and better names, related to what implementation stands for, can be chosen. That applies for the file names as well as constant names if you take the enum approach.